# Bash - Lots of elif, is there a best practice?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that works for but I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do it.

I run my script with an argument which will be the "stackname" and then I have conditions for each stack, An array will be created for each condition in case the condition is met.

I know that bash doesn't support two-dimensional array, So I'm trying to figure out the best practice of writing this script.

**This is the script below:**

```
export stackname=$1
if [[ ${stackname} == "aggregator" ]] ]]; then
    myArray=("awslocal" "db" "redis" "activemq")
elif [[ ${stackname} == "producer" ]]; then
    myArray=("awslocal" "db" "redis" "kafka" "activemq")
elif [[ ${stackname} == "service" ]]; then
    myArray=("db")
elif [[ ${stackname} == "event" ]]; then
    myArray=("awslocal" "db" "activemq" )
else
    printf "\e[40;33;1;4;106;41m----------------- $stackname Not valid!! - will fail the script--------------------\e[0m\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `case/esac` might be better

Comment: That's a matter of taste; which is subjective.

Comment: `"might be" != "is"`

Comment: CASE is usually executed somewhat faster that if/elif. Now is that difference significant is another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally used `case/esac` as @anubhava suggested, it looks much simpler in the eye:

```
export stackname=$1
case "${stackname}" in
  "aggregator") myArray=( "db" "redis" "activemq") ;;
  "producer") myArray=( "awslocal" "db" "redis" "kafka" "activemq") ;;
  "service") myArray=( "db" ) ;;
  "event") myArray=( "awslocal" "db" "activemq") ;;
  *) exit ;;
esac
for servicename in "${myArray[@]}"
do
    echo $servicename
done
```

Comment: ++ indeed this looks much easier to read

Comment: There is no reason to `export` the variable unless you have subprocesses later on in your script which require this variable to be set. Also, you can replace the loop with `printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"` and coincidentally get rid of one quoting problem.